# Pycharm not showing dropdown help for non-buitlin packages

Tags: python, import, ide, package, pycharm

I am practicing python packages programs. I have created few nested directories with

`__init__.py` files. But while importing these

modules IDE(pycharm) is not showing(helping) by automatically showing the possible options

after typing .(DOT) in IDE. But when we try to import built-in packages, python automatically

helps us after typing .(DOT), it shows possible modules. I have added package path to sys.path,

what more can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the root of your package structure is different from the root directory of the project, you need to mark it as a source root in PyCharm. For example, if your directory structure looks like:

```
myProject
  src
    mypackage
      __init__.py
      mymodule.py
```

and you're trying to import "mypackage.mymodule", the "src" directory needs to be marked as a source root. You can do it by selecting the corresponding action from the context menu on a directory in the Project view.